# Untiy3D: Detecting a collision without using the physics engine?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics

I have a nice trail renderer which moves steadly towards some other GameObjects and I need to know when the renderer "gets" to one of these GameObjects.

I've been looking around and it seems that, leaving aside the code controlling the collision itself, I need to:

1) Create a Collider (BoxCollider, for instance).

2) Attach to it a RigidBody, because moving the transform of the collider is not the best thing in terms of performance.

3) Apply a force to the RigidBody to make it move towards the objectives.

Overall, it seems like an overly complex setup to make if one object has *just collided* with another one, as I don't really it to do anything with physics (The ray won't bounce, nor come back, its all controlled by code).

Am I missing something or this is the only approach to this situation available on Unity?

Comment: You can attach a rigidbody and a boxcollider and use your current method of moving it in order to detect a collision. Since it does not sound like you are utilizing any physics, you do not need to use a Force. Colliders/rigidbodies are the quickest and easiest solution.

Comment: Are there colliders on the GameObjects that you want to detect the collision with?

Comment: @ryeMoss I have "no current method", besides of applying force (huh, maybe the correct term is "speed", but again, I'm overviewing what I have to do) to the RigidBody, so the BoxCollider moves with it.

Comment: @Serlite Yeah, the other objects do have colliders, but I'm asking if there's a different, less complex approach to this.

Comment: No, there's only a much more complex approach: write your own colliding system. ;)

Comment: @Neuromante Just the same, you can use any method to move your body if you don't need physics other than collision detection. Whether that be change the transform position, rigidbody position, velocity, or adding force

Comment: @Neuromante There are alternatives, though not necessarily simpler - you can add a script to the trail renderer object to execute [`Physics.CheckSphere()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckSphere.html) each physics frame, to manually detect colliders within a given space. This way, there's no need to have a collider on that object. In terms of moving the object, you can still use a RigidBody without a collider, or you can manually use Translate on it every frame.

Comment: Agree with what @Serlite said. You will still need a collider on the object that doesn't have the script. This will however save you from having a rigidbody on any of those objects. Plus you can call CheckSphere inside the Update() loop saving some load from the FixedUpdate() physics loop